# Keyframing constraints overwrite

Tags: animation

I have a `objectA`, and when I add a `copy location` constraint to it to another `objectB` with influence `0` at frame 10 and then add keyframe. Then on frame 11 I change the influence to `1` and add a keyframe, but when I go back to any frame from 1-10 I find that the influence is `1` as if it overwrote the inserted first keyframe which was inserted when the influence was `0`. Any advice please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keyframe the **influence value** of the `copy location constraint`:

- set the influence value to **0**
- go to the **frame before** the value should change
- place the mouse cursor on top of the **influence slider**
- press <kbd>I</kbd> to insert a keyframe
- jump to the **next frame** in the timeline with <kbd>→</kbd>
- set the infuence value to **1** and press <kbd>I</kbd> again

[image]